# Gradle Enterprise Gradle plugin (com.gradle.enterprise) not found error in jenkins when trying to build my project

Tags: jenkins, exception, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, enterprise

Iam using the Gradle 6.5 version installed on my linux server.I have configured Gradle in jenkins which resides on the same server.

I have set a Freestyle project job on jenkins to build using gradle.

when iam trying to build, i get an error as below:

Plugin [id: 'com.gradle.enterprise', version: '3.3.3', artifact: 'com.gradle:gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin:3.3.3'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.gradle:gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin:3.3.3')
  Searched in the following repositories:
  Gradle Central Plugin Repository

Can you please suggest me how i can resolve this issue.

Comment: Any luck? how did you fixed?

Comment: I have this same issue, anyone can you help?

Comment: How did you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 8):

Just remove `--offline` argument from gradle in settings

Answer (score 6):

My problem was being behind a firewall, which I "solved" by disconnecting from my company's VPN.

I also added `plugins.gradle.org/m2` as a repo:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    gradlePluginPortal()
}
```

Comment: Adding `gradlePluginPortal()` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Check in `build.gradle` that your `*classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin'*` dependency is updated. for me `*classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.5.12'*` is working.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `--offline` argument from Gradle in settings.
Steps:

1. Open the Gradle panel (usually on the right side of Android Studio).
2. Look for the toggle button resembling a power plug or an airplane symbol. This represents the offline mode state.
3. Click the toggle button to disable offline mode (if currently enabled).

[image: Screenshot]